# Subsequential limits of a sequence with $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| < \frac{1}{10}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence that has $0$ and $1$ as subsequential limits. Suppose that for every $n$, $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| < \frac{1}{10}.$
>   Prove that the set $PL({x_n})$ - (the set of all Subsequential limits of $x_{n}$) has at least $3$ objects.

I tried to prove it by contradiction, but I can't find a way to show that $PL({x_n})$ must have more than $2$ objects.

Comment: Next: What is the minimum size that $\operatorname{PL}(x_n)$ can have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| < \frac{1}{10}$ and $0$ and $1$ are subsequential limits, there are infinitely many $x_n$'s that belong to $(\frac{2}{10},\frac{8}{10})$. Therefore, there exists $x_{n_k}$ such that for all $k$, $x_{n_k}\in (\frac{2}{10},\frac{8}{10})$. But $(x_{n_k})_k$ is a bounded sequence, thus it has a subsequence $(x_{n_{m_k}})$ that converges to some $L\in [\frac{2}{10},\frac{8}{10}]$.

Besides $(x_{n_{m_k}})$ is subsequence of $(x_n)$.Thus $L\in PL(x_n)$, and $L\notin \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Could you explain why infinitely many ${x_n}'s$ that belong to $(\frac{2}{10},\frac{8}{10})$.?

Comment: There are infinitely many $n$'s such that $|x_n|<\frac{1}{100}$  and infinitely many $m$'s such that $|x_m-1|<\frac{1}{100}$. When $|x_n|<\frac{1}{100}$, you know there is some $m>n$ such that $|x_m-1|<\frac{1}{100}$. Since the sequence can make leaps of at most $\frac 1{10}$, there is some $p\in (n,m)$ such that $x_p\in (\frac{2}{10},\frac{8}{10})$

Comment: To the proposer: Regarding why there are infinitely many $n$ such that $x_n\in (2/10,8/10):$... For any $m\in \Bbb N$ there exists $m'>m $ such that  $x_{m'}<1/10$ and $m''>m'$ such that $x_{m''}>9/10>2/10..$.. So consider the least $n>m'$ such that $a_n>2/10.$  Then  $a_{n-1}\leq 1/10 $ so $2/10<a_n\leq a_{n-1}+1/10 \leq 1/10+1/10<8/10.$